# Installing 'Kubuntu 14.04'

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, kubuntu, iso

I don't want to retain my WinXP so I downloaded 'Kubunu 14.04'. However, I can't find it at all, even in my BIOS. Should I download it again?

Comment: Did you install it (by using a USB flash drive or burning it to a CD)?

Answer (score -1):

No, There is no need to download Kubuntu again, If you dont need your WinXP, just install kubuntu, and you can purge all disk to install.

If your installation is successful, you must login to kubuntu without any problem (At the last step Kubuntu will ask you to reboot, on successful installation)